# Database integration of Rails and Laravel apps

Tags: database, mysql, ruby-on-rails, laravel

I have some very small apps on a VPS running ruby on rails and a co-worker also have some of his own apps running on laravel at another VPS.
So far we dont needed to share any data among the apps, but we are currently developing something that would have some overlaping database tables like a `Users` table.
How would you make that integration? Create a mysql database for all apps to connect?
Is there someway to "replicate" `User`updates on a database to another one?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest creating web service to store such users. It's easier to maintain and test with such soulution. You don't want to coordinate development of every tool each time you need to update DB schema, do you?